# How can I fasten pink polystyrene wall insulation into a structure?

Tags: insulation

I got a big polystyrene board from Home Depot (you know, the kind with Pink Panther on it). I want to glue it together with Liquid Nails to make a house for feral cats in my neighborhood.

However,

1. I noticed that it's laminated on both sides. Should I remove the lamination so that the actual foam adheres and not the laminate?
2. Will giving it a few coats of paint make it waterproof? If not, should I try something else?

Comment: I would think a cat would shred that material with their claws.

Comment: Yep, that very well might happen. If they destroy it I'll try rebuilding trying something else. I want to try finding cheap bulk ice chests, but none are the right size and price. I could also coat it in plastic on both sides but that makes it more difficult to build...

Comment: Cultivating feral cats is usually against local ordinances (and certainly doesn't endear you with your neighbors). It also [contributes to the destruction of huge numbers of songbirds and other wildlife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_predation_on_wildlife#Birds). Just don't.

Comment: Feeding and sheltering feral cats creates more feral cats. When a feral has to forage and hunt for its own survival they come into heat much less frequently so they have fewer kittens. On the other hand keeping their bellies full of store bought food leads to frequent cycles of fertility and produces many times more feral cats that will also reproduce leading to a much larger population of  unwanted feral cats.

Comment: That's fair. I'm designing this because I saw a video of shelters that drill holes in ice coolers to create shelters for feral cats that they've captured, spayed and released (which is a rational thing to do if you don't want more strays, but also don't want to kill animals). I think I can build a better cat shelter, and if not at least it will be a fun project.  I think it's becoming increasingly clear that it at least needs an outer shell. I'm considering thin plywood just to provide weatherproofing, and gluing hardier foam to the inside of that.

Comment: Releasing the cat (spayed or not) kills far more animals than killing the cat would, as I explained. You're being irrational. Nature kills animals by the billions every day, and putting one to sleep is the humane, sensible thing to do. Capture the animal and turn it over to animal control or a shelter. It's the only responsible outcome.

Comment: What is "laminated" onto the foam?  You need a product that is compatible with the lamination material.  If it's foil this probably means an epoxy or polyester resin.  For plastics you'd need a glue compatible with the plastic.

Comment: Test your paint on a piece of scrap foam before painting your structure. Some paints (especially spray paint) will have solvents that will melt the plastic.

Comment: Related question that doesn't exist: how can I piss off my neighbors to the point of them calling animal services on me? Don't get me wrong, I love cats; I have two. But they're spayed, neutered, indoor/outdoor, *not* declawed, and have distemper, de-wormer, FLV, and rabies shots. Without all of those, you should limit your contact with them, but you're still helping spread all those viruses, and breading more cats which repeats the cycle.

Comment: Actually these cats live at a nearby flooring shop and the owner who seems pretty nice (despite how you may feel about feral cats) feeds them. I don't, and I agree you should at least neuter and release. The main reason I'm doing this project is to post it on YouTube and make a better design for rescues and people who own barn cats.

Comment: I agree with Isherwood , my step dad has a soft spot and was feeding some strays , soon there were close to 50, he had them spayed , neutered, but still fed them , last time I went down to visit them we noticed their weren’t many cats but a family of skunks moved in , dad had not seen them, so by housing and feeding strays he ended up with a bunch of other critters that were a lot more difficult to deal with.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, as has been said, that material will not hold up to either the cats or the weather. You need an actual siding over it.

The construction adhesive you mentioned will eat the foam unless it's the water-based "panel" or "project" variety. The solvent in the heavy duty type dissolves polystyrene.

I built a similar "hot box" for my dog using the same stuff. I assembled six panels by creating a frame of 2x2, fitting 1-1/2" foam inside, and screwing 1/4" BC plywood to both faces. I strategically extended the plywood 2" on one face as needed to create the lap necessary to screw the other panels in place. It's extremely solid and comfortable. I have it mounted off the ground by just the front panel, and I can stand on it with no movement whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Yellow gorilla glue works well on foam, and won't melt it. It needs a little moisture to work so apply a light mist of water to one side, and a thin bead of glue to the other. (Wood normally has sufficient moisture already, but foam has none). Hold it together with tape while the glue sets, and wipe up the extra every 10 minutes for about an hour - it expands a lot, foaming up to fill gaps and making a mess if you're not careful.

Epoxy works too, but is expensive and requires mixing.

UHU POR is a specialist glue for foam, but it's designed for craft work and small pieces, not construction. I use it when gorilla glue is too messy.

If the laminate is a polythene sheet, you should remove it in the areas you want to glue, as almost no glues stick to polythene. Keep the laminate for waterproofing, and use parcel tape to cover any gaps.

Or you could just use parcel tape to hold it together, it can be as good as glue.

Answer (score 0):

Several companies make a foamboard adhesive. [Loctite PL300 Foamboard](https://www.loctiteproducts.com/en/products/build/construction-adhesives/loctite_pl_300_vocfoamboardadhesive.html) is one.

The foamboard will be waterproof (at least as far as your needs are concerned) as it is. It is not fireproof, however. It's also very light, so unless you're also building some sort of structure to hold it in place, the first wind will send it flying.

No comment on the material being cat-proof.

Answer (score 0):

Loctite PL300 Foamboard is good, but Loctite PL Premium also says it glues XPS (Pink) foam - [Product page, see tech data sheet](https://www.loctiteproducts.com/en/products/build/construction-adhesives/loctite_pl_premiumpolyurethaneconstructionadhesive.html) – I have used both in the past few days (Foamboard to glue pieces to each other, and PL to glue foam to wood) – but I didn't remove any laminate. Both glues seem OK, but "mechanical" fasteners are often called for. In other words, while PL glue is stronger than wood fibers themselves, I don't think you're gluing foam into a singular unit, and most instructions are about attaching foam to something, not making a crate.

Also, I know from experience that animals don't mind ripping the pink foam to pieces (mice, rats, racoons, groundhogs) if they decide that's important to them.

Also, that stuff is EXPENSIVE compared to a sheet of even high-quality OSB, which you could nail and glue into something really strong – but maybe you're trying to make something simple. Here the PL glue would come in more handy because it glues lots of things together, you could even glue the box to concrete. Costwise, thinner insulation and OSB together might be stronger, and not blow away. I guess you're trying to add some insulation, but you could just get old clothes or blankets – I'm sure feral cats aren't picky.